# Contain draggable to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I write a userscript for a website, and the script includes a jQuery UI `draggable`. Greatly simplified, the site has two rows, and each row has two divs placed horizontally.

The site layout previously used two *columns* with inner divs instead of *rows*. The draggable was constrained to the right column's parent, which is exactly what we wanted. Now, however, there's no way to constrain to the right "column" because that column no longer exists in the DOM.

Is there a way to fluidly contain the draggable div to the right column of divs without the old parent element? I can add elements to the DOM (or do whatever) if needed, we have the full power of jQuery and jQuery UI available. I know it would be possible to use a `droppable` on the top right div, but from what I understand that would cause the draggable to snap between the two. If that's the only option then I'll do that, but if there's another method I would love to see it.

#### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xmLtet8r/)

```
<div id="outercontainer">
  <div id="toprow">
    <div id="topleft"></div>
    <div id="topright"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomrow">
    <div id="bottomleft"></div>
    <div id="bottomright"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dragme"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. The draggable should should be dropped only in `topright` & `bottomright` ..?

Comment: @TJ Yes, that is correct. I want the draggable to be used anywhere in the right "column" (`topright` and `bottomright`). Being able to move between the two fluidly, i.e. no snapping between the two, would be ideal, though I understand if that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual **containment** value used in constraining position is an array of coordinates that's being calculated based on the object you set in the options themselves. But you can access this containment property on the draggable instance and modify them as you wish. The only restriction is that it needs to be a rectangle, you cannot mix shapes.

In your case, you can simply work out the coordinates from the elements.

```
$("#dragme").draggable({
  // You still need to set a value for containment
  // else it won't be checked when evaluating the position
  containment: 'document',
  start: function(e, ui) {
    // You simply set a left, top, right, bottom coordinates.
    // You need to set it on start so if the elements have been
    // resized, the containment follows.
    var cont = [
      $('#topleft').offset().left + $('#topleft').outerWidth(),
      $('#toprow').offset().top,
      $('#toprow').offset().left + $('#toprow').outerWidth() - ui.helper.width(),
      $('#bottomrow').offset().top + $('#bottomrow').outerHeight() - ui.helper.height(),
    ]

    $(this).draggable('instance').containment = cont;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nxxbh8eL/